# asio HTTPS request response body is non printable unicode characters

Tags: c++11, https, get, asio

i'm trying to send a get request to get some information, and I am using asio and a https request and ssl. When I send the request, I get a fully formed header, but the response is just non printable unicode characters. Despite the response not being readable, it has the same amount of characters as what the response is supposed have. Below is my code, and the response I get.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#include "asio.hpp"
#include "asio/ssl.hpp"

using namespace std;

float getTickerValue(const string& ticker)
{
    float tickerPrice;
    string host = "query1.finance.yahoo.com";
    string portNumber = "80";

    typedef asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssl_socket;

    // Create a context that uses the default paths for
    // finding CA certificates.
    asio::ssl::context ctx(asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    // Open a socket and connect it to the remote host.
    asio::io_service io_service;
    ssl_socket sock(io_service, ctx);
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(host, "https");
    asio::connect(sock.lowest_layer(), resolver.resolve(query));
    sock.lowest_layer().set_option(asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));

    // Perform SSL handshake and verify the remote host's
    // certificate.
    sock.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    sock.set_verify_callback(asio::ssl::rfc2818_verification(host));
    sock.handshake(ssl_socket::client);

    // ... read and write as normal ...
    {
        string request = "GET /v11/finance/quoteSummary/" + ticker + "?modules=financialData HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                                                                     "Host: " + host + "\r\n"
                                                                     "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        sock.write_some(asio::buffer(request.data(), request.size()));

        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);  // THIS IS TEMPORARY

        size_t bytes = sock.lowest_layer().available();
        cout << "Bytes avalible: " << bytes << endl;

        if (bytes > 0) {
            vector<char> vBuffer(bytes);
            sock.read_some(asio::buffer(vBuffer.data(), vBuffer.size()));
            for (auto c: vBuffer) {
                cout << c;
            }
        }
    }
    return tickerPrice;
}
```

[image: response from code]

Thanks!

Comment: Number of bytes actually read is returned by `read_some` you should use it instead of `lowest_layer` data. And you should not expect to receive all data in a single read even when providing large buffer. For HTTP if you specify `connection: close` in the request, you should read data in a loop until server closes the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Making those changes still results in the body being non printable unicode characters tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk what the problem was. I tried doing requests on different websites but the response was always un-readable. I just ended up using boost/beast to do the request instead and it worked.